# unable to access fields in json objects from an array of json objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

This is the array of JSON objects I get when I am doing a query on MongoDB using Mongoose library. I am getting a response in the form of an array. Now I am trying to generate the customised JSON object and send it across as a response

```
[{
    _id: 5 c759f301b164e139f2df980,
    Sno: 1,
    MaterialName: 'Material1',
    MaterialId: '0000000000000000ABCDA001',
    LocationName: 'RWH_S1_SZ_AL1',
    LocationId: '00000000000000001111A001',
    Quantity: '50',
    DeliveryLocationName: 'IN4_SEC1',
    DeliveryLocationID: '00000000000000003333C001',
    PickedUp: 'Yes/No(1/0)',
    PickTimeStamp: null,
    Delivered: 'Yes/No(1/0)',
    DeliveryTimeStamp: null
},
{
    _id: 5 c759f301b164e139f2df981,
    Sno: 2,
    MaterialName: 'Material2',
    MaterialId: '0000000000000000ABCDB001',
    LocationName: 'RWH_S1_SZ_AL2',
    LocationId: '00000000000000001111A001',
    Quantity: '10',
    DeliveryLocationName: 'IN4_SEC1',
    DeliveryLocationID: '00000000000000003333C001',
    PickedUp: null,
    PickTimeStamp: null,
    Delivered: null,
    DeliveryTimeStamp: null
},
{
    _id: 5 c759f301b164e139f2df982,
    Sno: 3,
    MaterialName: 'Material3',
    MaterialId: '0000000000000000ABCDC001',
    LocationName: 'RWH_S1_SZ_AL3',
    LocationId: '00000000000000002222B001',
    Quantity: '30',
    DeliveryLocationName: 'IN4_SEC1',
    DeliveryLocationID: '00000000000000003333C001',
    PickedUp: null,
    PickTimeStamp: null,
    Delivered: null,
    DeliveryTimeStamp: null
}]
```

I am getting this array as a response(resp) to a MongoDB query using mongoose.

Now I am trying to generate customized JSON objects by accessing the fields from the received JSON objects array.so when I am doing like this below here 5 is no of objects in the JSON array

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var json = {
        LINE1: "MaterialName": resp[i].MaterialName,
        "MaterialId": resp[i].MaterialId,
        "LocationName": resp[i].LocationName,
        "LocationId": resp[i].LocationId,
        "Quantity": resp[i].Quantity,
        "DeliveryLocationName": resp[i].DeliveryLocationName,
        "DeliveryLocationId": resp[i].DeliveryLocationId
    }
}
```

Type error comes up and says property 0 not defined at LINE1 is there a problem with accessing the array this way. What should I do now? please help me.

Comment: the json array you mentioned above, is that stored in resp variable ?

Comment: One more mistake in your code is, you outlined your array has 5 elements. But you're running for loop 6 times, from 0 till <=5 -- this will make the loop run 6 times. It should be < 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that this syntax is not valid:

```js
var json = {
    LINE1: "foo": "bar", "lala": "lolo"
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

You need to declare the `LINE1` key as an `object`, like this:

```js
var json = {
    LINE1: {"foo": "bar", "lala": "lolo"}
}

console.log(json);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
```

So, your code should be reworked like this:

```
var json;

for (var i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; i++)
{ 
    json = {
        LINE1: {
            "MaterialName": resp[i].MaterialName,
            "MaterialId": resp[i].MaterialId,
            "LocationName": resp[i].LocationName,
            "LocationId": resp[i].LocationId,
            "Quantity": resp[i].Quantity,
            "DeliveryLocationName": resp[i].DeliveryLocationName,
            "DeliveryLocationId": resp[i].DeliveryLocationId
        }
    }

    // TODO: Do something with json variable or will be
    // overwrite by next iterations.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Assuming the large JSON you shared here (coming from MongoDB) is present in resp variable.

```
var resp = [{}];  //This is your large array coming from MongoDB.

function getCustomJsonObject(resp){
    var outputArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i< resp.length; i++){
        var jsonObj = {
             "MaterialName": resp[i].MaterialName,
             "MaterialId": resp[i].MaterialId,
             "LocationName": resp[i].LocationName,
             "LocationId": resp[i].LocationId,
             "Quantity": resp[i].Quantity,
             "DeliveryLocationName": resp[i].DeliveryLocationName,
             "DeliveryLocationId": resp[i].DeliveryLocationId
        }
        outputArray.push(jsonObj);     
    }
    return outputArray;
}

var customObj = getCustomJsonObject(resp);
```